# Why AnnotationMetadata was based on ASM rather than Java Reflection

Tags: java, spring, java-bytecode-asm

The implementation `AnnotationMetadata` was based on ASM rather than Java Reflection?  Is it possible to speed up resolve meta data from Annotation?

Comment: Are you asking if you can speed up some code implemented with ASM by using Java Reflection?

Comment: Yes, I found there are two implementation regarding Annotation meta data, one is ASM , another is  Java Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

The typical motivation to re-implement annotation processing instead of using the builtin Reflection facility is to gain more robustness regarding absent classes, as the builtin facility usually fails as soon as an annotation refers to a missing type, even if that annotation is not related to the one you want to query.

It is unlikely that one implementation is faster than the other, as they are basically doing the same, processing byte arrays according to the same formal rules [given by the Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.16). The only notable effect may arise from sharing of previously evaluated annotations, if multiple queries for the same program element are made. But then, it depends on which framework the other code used, whether the effect will be positive (obviously, it will be a benefit if all code uses the same framework).